# Trying to serialize a struct containing Unicode text

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to serialize a struct that contains a number of members, including a couple of strings of Unicode text (wchar_t, coded as Windows TCHARs), to save to a file later.  I want to serialize it as a unit rather than write the individual members of the struct separately because there are a number of different structs that need to be saved (each one will have its own serialization function), and I want to be able to pass a struct, once serialized, to a generic function that will wrap it with some metadata before actually writing it to the file (and adding it to the accompanying index I am also creating).

However, while the integers serialize and deserialize just fine, the strings, once unserialized, appear as essentially random text (changing each time).

Here is my serialization function:

```
PBYTE SerializeLanguage(language *Language){
    PBYTE SerializedLanguage;
    SIZE_T LanguageLen;
    UINT CurrentIndex = 0;

    LanguageLen = GetSerializedLanguageLength(Language);

    SerializedLanguage = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, LanguageLen);

    CopyMemory(&SerializedLanguage[CurrentIndex], &(Language->name_length), sizeof(Language->name_length));
    CurrentIndex += sizeof(Language->name_length);

    CopyMemory(&SerializedLanguage[CurrentIndex], &(Language->name), (lstrlen(Language->name) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));

    return SerializedLanguage;
}
```

And my de-serialization function:

```
VOID DeserializeLanguage(language *Out, PBYTE SerializedLanguage){
    UINT CurrentIndex = 0;

    CopyMemory(&(Out->name_length), &SerializedLanguage[CurrentIndex], sizeof(Out->name_length));
    CurrentIndex += sizeof(Out->name_length);

    Out->name = (PTCHAR)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, Out->name_length);
    CopyMemory(Out->name, &SerializedLanguage[CurrentIndex], Out->name_length);

    MessageBox(NULL, Out->name, NULL, MB_OK);

    return;
}
```

And, finally, the language struct:

```
typedef struct language {
    UINT name_length;
    PTCHAR name;

    UINT script_name_length; /* Serialization for this and the following elements not yet implemented */
    PTCHAR script_name;
    BYTE min_level;
} language;
```

I've checked with a debugger, and language.name is allocated and has already been assigned correctly in the function that calls SerializeLanguage.

UNICODE is defined so all the wide-character versions of the relevant functions are being called; this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem, in the second argument:

```
CopyMemory(&SerializedLanguage[CurrentIndex], &(Language->name), 
    (lstrlen(Language->name) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```

You're copying the pointer, not the content.  This should work:

```
CopyMemory(&SerializedLanguage[CurrentIndex], Language->name, 
    (lstrlen(Language->name) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```